# Creating A Keyword Dashboard In Google Sheets With The Ability To Filter Out Types Of Conversions

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, pivot-table, spreadsheet, dashboard

I'm importing live data from Google Ads for all the accounts I manage, I want to create a dashboard that lets me look at clicks, costs, cost/conversion per keyword.

However, the conversions counted in the conversion column aren't always relevant (each account has 2-10 different types of conversions). My goal is to make a dataset that can be filtered by **account name** and then I can select which of the conversion actions that occurred in that account during that period will be represented in the 'Conv. Column'.

I have all the data required in the tab **Full Data Set**, where I have linked two tabs using unique IDs (Ad Group, Search Keyword, Search Keyword Match Type, & Week all combined).

The current **Full Data Set** looks like this:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/18IUG.png)

You'll notice that columns K and beyond are the **conversion action** names in the header row and the rows below will have a count of the conversions on that respective week, keyword... Etc.

I have tried for days to figure out how to:

1. Filter out the Conversion Action columns with no conversions for a specific client
   (I would love a view that shows only the keyword data for one Account and relevant conversion actions for that account).
2. With a list of Conversion Actions That are >0 For any certain account,

Here's a simplification of the issue:
I already did this; combined the two tables into one. Keep in mind that in reality, these are large arrays with many variables.
[image]

Next here is a concept of what I am hoping to achieve. Mainly how to create the 'list of conversions' (circled in red) and how to make those checkboxes affect the data in the tables. (Circled in green is where that data comes from).
[image]

Spreadsheet link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UXjTsBFvHy_8i9p7fcSNVcUhpks8j9-i7cnT1l3yzvU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I am having a hard time following what it is you're looking for. Perhaps someone else will be able to understand better and help you, or if you could mockup a sheet of desired results/look that may help get to an answer.

Comment: @KevinP. I made some changes to simplify what I am asking and made an example. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 1):

This is very close to what I think it is you're looking for.

[image: Example]

```
=QUERY({MAP(QUERY({$A$2:$J$14},"SELECT Col2, Col3, Col4, SUM(Col5) "&TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,ARRAYFORMULA(IF($I19:$I20=TRUE, ", SUM(Col" & ARRAYFORMULA(IF($I19:$I20, MATCH($H19:$H20, $A$2:$I$2, 0), ""))&")", "")))&" WHERE Col4 = '"&$E19&"' AND Col1 <= "&$C19&" AND Col1 >= "&$B19&" GROUP BY Col2, Col3, Col4 LABEL SUM(Col5) 'Cost' "&TEXTJOIN("", TRUE, ARRAYFORMULA(IF($I19:$I20=TRUE, ", SUM(Col" & ARRAYFORMULA(IF($I19:$I20, MATCH($H19:$H20, $A$2:$I$2, 0), ""))&") '"&ARRAYFORMULA(IF($I19:$I20, $H19:$H20, ""))&"'", "")))&""), LAMBDA(X, IF(X="", 0, X)))},"SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, "&TEXTJOIN(" + ",TRUE,ARRAYFORMULA("SUM(Col"&SEQUENCE(COUNTIF(I19:I20,TRUE),1,5)&")"))&" GROUP BY Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4"&TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,ARRAYFORMULA(", Col"&SEQUENCE(COUNTIF(I19:I20,TRUE),1,5)))&" LABEL "&TEXTJOIN(" + ",TRUE,ARRAYFORMULA("SUM(Col"&SEQUENCE(COUNTIF(I19:I20,TRUE),1,5)&")"))&" 'Conv(SUM)'"&"")
```

Breaking it down, since it is very complex we have formula's calculating which columns we need to include based on the checkbox state and the column name to the left of that checkbox.

`A1:J14` is your range to look through

`I19:I20` are your checkboxes for each parameter (Appt Booked, Viewed Appt Page, Purchase, Clicked_Button, etc...)

`H19:H20` is your checkbox column headers (left of your checkbox)

`A2:I2` are your actual column headers that contain the counts

`E19` is the Client

`C19` is the End Week

`B19` is the Start Week

This should return a query of results based on what is checked. Note that at least one item must be checked.

The provided formula will work in it's current condition for the Sample given of Doctor's Office and Doct Appt.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time on this! This is really close to what I need. The one note, which could help this problem is that I was looking to have the list of conversion actions under the column header named 'List of Conv." automatically populate based on which conversion actions have a value in them for this filtered range. So that it's relevant to each view. Does that make sense?

Comment: If I understand what I think you mean, you are asking for a separate formula to populate the checkbox range based on the Start, End, and Client parameters? Meaning any column that has a value related to the keywords will populate a list of check boxes for those headers? Also I got the function to run properly in handling `NULL` values. Take a look at the updated formula :)